# Unity/ARCore on Samsung Galaxy S8 - camera image is stretched

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I started playing around with ARCore through unity and testing on a Samsung galaxy S8.

Everything seems to be working fine but the video image that is displayed in the background (done automatically by ARCore) appears stretched vertically. I know the camera aspect on that device doesn't match the weird aspect of the phone's screen but I couldn't find a way to work around this.

This also happens when I build the small sample that comes with the ARCore package. Anyone else run into this?

Comment: Are you on 2017.1.b10? That version of Unity has a bug. Try using b9. It has a more stable version of ARCore.

Comment: I was using b9 (now b11). It's not stability that's the problem, the video aspect is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the Unity implementation of ARCore according to this [thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/arcore-samsung-s8-video-stretched-vertically.495372/).

For those interested, We actually ended up doing fancy shader work to 'un-stretch' the image while pre-stretching all our content so we end up with a correct image - pretty ugly solution and I will happily yank this part out of the project as soon as a fix is issued.

Comment: your solutions sounds interesting. Do you have your shader code published somewhere?